# Receive an EnumSet from a spring form checkbox element?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, enums, enumset

I've seen a few related questions on this topic but none that seem to exactly match what I'm after.

I have a form where I'd like the user to be able to select a number of items from a checkbox list (backed by an enum), and to receive that as a Set. I have the following (using days as an example)

My enum:

```
public enum Day {
MONDAY,
TUESDAY,
WEDNESDAY,
THURSDAY,
FRIDAY,
SATURDAY,
SUNDAY
}
```

Sending the enum values to the page in the controller to be displayed as the options:

```
model.addAttribute("allDays", Day.values());
```

Writing the options as checkboxes and mapping to correct form field:

```
<form:form method="get" modelAttribute="filterForm" commandName="filterForm">
    <c:forEach items="${allDays}" var="item">
        <form:checkbox path="days" value="${item.name()}" label="${item.name()}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

The form object backing the form:

```
public class FilterForm {

    private EnumSet<Day> days;

    public EnumSet<Day> getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(EnumSet<Day> days) {
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```

This works as far as showing the options correctly, but when I try to submit, I get an error:

> org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'filterForm' on field 'days': rejected value
>   [0,1]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.filterForm.days,typeMismatch.days,typeMismatch.java.util.EnumSet,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [filterForm.days,days]; arguments []; default message [days]];
>   default message [Failed to convert property value of type
>   'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.EnumSet' for property
>   'days'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String[] to type
>   java.util.EnumSet for value '{0, 1}';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   instantiate Collection type: java.util.EnumSet]
>     org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Any idea what the problem is or if there is a better way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by changing my form to use Set instead of EnumSet, and I also modified the  tag so that the submitted values would remain selected:

```
<form:form method="get" modelAttribute="filterForm" commandName="filterForm">
    <form:checkboxes items="${allDays}" path="days" />
</form:form>
```

And the Form:

```
public class FilterForm {

    private Set<Day> days;

    public Set<Day> getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(Set<Day> days) {
        this.days = days;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to work with interfaces instead of implementations.

You can still use an EnumSet, but the declaration needs to use interfaces (it's a good practice anyway).

In other words, use the code provided by [Abby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135490/819651). Then, you can do stuff like:

```
filterForm.setDays(EnumSet.allOf(Day.class));
```